# How to connect my smart contract with another deployed smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

Assalamualaikum,

I am new to blockchain. So I was thinking of deploying  a smart contract as rest api, and use it in my another smart contract.
Is it possible?
I know oracle  helps to fetch data but can it help interacting  two deployed contracts?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an interface of the target contract in the source contract. Example:

*TargetContract*, deployed on the `0x123` address:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract TargetContract {
    function foo() external pure returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

*SourceContract*, pointing to the `0x123` `TargetContract`

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface ITargetContract {
    function foo() external returns (bool);
}

contract SourceContract {
    function baz() external {
        ITargetContract targetContract = ITargetContract(address(0x123));
        bool returnedValue = targetContract.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank  a lot for your answer. It worked for me. But I am very confused, is it a good practice?  Should we use a deployed  smart contract  from multiple  dapps like we use api in multiple centralized apps?

Comment: It's a very common practice. For example: The target contract is of an established DEX, and the source contract allows to buy a specific token through the DEX... So kind of like if the DEX was publishing an API, and the source contract was calling the API.